# PostgreSQL mac base permissions error

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm having an issue of running off a postgresql database backup that I brought over from a failed Mac. The database was running just fine on the last few days of the previous Mac, but since I've transferred it over, configured the settings, and installations to match the old server. I keep getting a permissions error when booting up the PostgreSQL service. Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this? The error is below.

*Could not access directory "base/12181": Permission Denied.*

I've gone through, and even downloaded the same version, binaries, and matched everything that I could. To which I still can't figure out what is causing this. All applications have full permissions to access the necessary folders, and I'm at a loss at this point. Any tips on what to look for, or do would be most helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -ld /path/to/datadir/base` and `ls -ld /path/to/datadir/base/12181` . Also, what user is your PostgreSQL server configured to run as? `postgres` or `postgres_` or something else?

Comment: I actually figured it out. The schema for Mac to PC was for some reason not linking correctly with the database. After talking to a rep that helps with Postgres support issues. We resolved the issue by using a different dump method, and that seemed to have worked.